# How to avoid memory leaks with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, memory-leaks

I have a **node** app with **express** and **mongoose**.
We are planning to have more than 40k users on our app this year.
So i want to **scale up my application**.

I have then setup a simple charge test using [Artillery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/artillery)
This test is calling a simple route on my api witch is doing a simple findOne request like so :

`await model.findOne(filter).lean().exec();`

My api is using only one mongoose connection like so :

```
    const options: ConnectOptions = {maxPoolSize: 15, minPoolSize:5};
    const databaseConnection : Connection = await new Mongoose().createConnection(mongoUri, options);
```

I'm running 200 requests/seconds for 10 seconds, for a total of 2000 findOne() requests.

**The issue is that my server is crashing due to K8S shutting him down because of it's memory going upper than 350MB**.

I have tried this on my local machine,  same result. My server is using 30MB by default, and when i start sending my 200requests/s this go up to 400MB before returning to it's 30MB.

It is worth mentioning that i'm using inversify on my app.
I tried to pass everything in singleton scope without significant changes...

I tried to recreate the same environment with a simple api like this.

## And in this case **i don't have memory leaks**...

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoString = 'mongodb://xxx:xxx@localhost/xxxxdb?retryWrites=true&ssl=false'
const myshema = require('./model');

const connection  = new mongoose.createConnection(mongoString, {    maxPoolSize:25,
    minPoolSize : 15});


connection.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error)
})

connection.once('connected', () => {
    console.log('Database Connected');
})
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(7894, () => {
    console.log(`Server Started at ${7894}`)
    
})

app.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const model = getMongooseModel(connection, 'myCollection',myshema)
    const result = await model.findOne({_id:"636a78909423a657b90ec1ad"}).lean();
    return res.status(200).json(result)
});

function getMongooseModel(
    db,
    collectionName,
    schema
) {
    if(collectionName in db.models) {
        return db.models[collectionName];
    }
    return db.model(collectionName, schema);
};
```

Any idea ?
Thanks